# Add Google custom search to wordpress.com

Tags: search, google-search, wordpress.com-hosting

I would like to add Google custom search to my wordpress.com site.

I have pasted HTML code from custom search to text widget in a sidebar, but instead of search box, I got text:

```
Loading
google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'}); google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('007267089725385613265:gmydx5gtw6u'); customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.LARGE_RESULTSET); var options = new google.search.DrawOptions(); options.setAutoComplete(true); customSearchControl.draw('cse', options); }, true);
```

I guess wordpress.com does not allow Google's JavaScript to execute.

Am I doing something wrong? Can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[JavaScript is not allowed on WordPress.com blogs.](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/#javascript)**